# Data entry mask using table forms with r

Tags: r, input, tabular

I would like to enter data using a tabular form from the r console or alternative.

The read command allows the data entry with r. However, the input fields are one below the other. 
Is there a possibility to create a form which would have a similar structure as shown below.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Hey! Can you provide data? What have you tried?

Comment: I did not get you question... you want a form as an input? But R does not provide any direct input mechanism (except from command line or reading files).